# How to solve stopped windows service 'clr.dll error?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

Hi; i have a windows service. i want to start my windows service by a batch file(.bat file). i do it succesfully. 
My service is starting very good. But 4-5 seconds later stop itself. Not working 4-5 seconds later.if i look my event logs on my windows server 2008,
an error occured. My error is below. How can i solve this problem?

```
Faulting application name: MyProject.WindowsService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4ffec57c
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.269, time stamp: 0x4ee9ae83
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x003565fd
Faulting process id: 0x1bbc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd60323465e0b0
Faulting application path: C:\MyProject.WindowsService\bin\Debug\MyProject.WindowsService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 742f8164-cc25-11e1-ae08-00155d100687
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0xc00000fd` indicates a stack overflow.

- Are you calling Win32 apis using p/invoke?
- Can you add some logging to the application and see how far it gets before faulting
- Does it fail when running as an application (not as a service?)